# List commits associated with a given tag with JGit

Tags: java, jgit

I need to create a history file that details all tags and for each tag, all its commits.

I've tried to call `getTags()` on the repository object and use those object id's, but they are not commit id's.

I also tried to use `getAllRefsByPeeledObjectId()` on the repository and that does bring back commits but I can't associate them to tags.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

**List all Tags:**

```
List<Ref> call = new Git(repository).tagList().call();
for (Ref ref : call) {
    System.out.println("Tag: " + ref + " " + ref.getName() + " " + ref.getObjectId().getName());
}
```

**List commits based on tag:**

I'd use the log-command based on the tag-name with the peeled-magic as noted by Rüdiger:

```
        LogCommand log = new Git(repository).log();

        Ref peeledRef = repository.peel(ref);
        if(peeledRef.getPeeledObjectId() != null) {
            log.add(peeledRef.getPeeledObjectId());
        } else {
            log.add(ref.getObjectId());
        }

        Iterable<RevCommit> logs = log.call();
        for (RevCommit rev : logs) {
            System.out.println("Commit: " + rev /* + ", name: " + rev.getName() + ", id: " + rev.getId().getName() */);
        }
```

See also my [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/) for some related examples.

Answer (score 4):

To get a list of tags you can either use `Repository#getTags()` or the `ListTagCommand`.

There are annotated and unannotated tags in Git. While unannotated tags directly point to the commit they were placed on, an annotated tag points to a *git object* that holds - among other meta data like a message - the commit-id.

The learning test below ilustrates this:

```
public class TagLearningTest {

  @Rule
  public final TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  private Git git;

  @Test
  public void testUnannotatedTag() throws Exception {
    RevCommit commit = git.commit().setMessage("Tag Me!").call();
    
    Ref tagRef = git.tag().setAnnotated(false).setName("Unannotated_Tag").call();
    
    assertEquals(commit.getId(), tagRef.getObjectId());
    assertNull(git.getRepository().peel(tagRef).getPeeledObjectId());
  }

  @Test
  public void testAnnotatedTag() throws Exception {
    RevCommit commit = git.commit().setMessage("Tag Me!").call();
    
    Ref tagRef = git.tag().setAnnotated(true).setName("Annotated_Tag").call();
    
    assertEquals(commit, git.getRepository().peel(tagRef).getPeeledObjectId());
    ObjectReader objectReader = git.getRepository().newObjectReader();
    ObjectLoader objectLoader = objectReader.open(tagRef.getObjectId());
    RevTag tag = RevTag.parse(objectLoader.getBytes());
    objectReader.release();
    assertEquals(commit.getId(), tag.getObject());
  }
  
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws GitAPIException {
    git = Git.init().setDirectory(tempFolder.getRoot()).call();
  }
}
```

In JGit, an annotated tag is represented by a `RevTag` that is stored under the id to which the tag ref points to.

To tell one form the other, you can *peel* the ref and then test if its `getPeeledObjectId()` returns non-null.

```
Ref peeledRef = git.getRepository().peel( tagRef );
boolean annotatedTag = peeledRef.getPeeledObjectId() != null;
```

The peeled object id is the one that points to the commit on which the annotated tag was created.