# Building a tag with jGit binds it to an unexpected ObjectId

Tags: jgit

in the following code snippet:

```
Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(path).call();
File testfile = new File(path, "testfile");
testfile.createNewFile();
git.add().addFilepattern("testfile").call();
RevCommit commit = git.commit().setMessage("test commit #1").call();
Ref tag = git.tag().setObjectId(commit).setName("tag1.0").call();

System.out.println("HEAD: " + git.getRepository().resolve(Constants.HEAD));
System.out.println("COMMIT: " + commit.toString());
System.out.println("TAG: " + tag.getObjectId());
```

I get the following printed:

```
AnyObjectId[1f74b8249ea41ebbe3305536def4b430130d366c]
commit 1f74b8249ea41ebbe3305536def4b430130d366c 1638417816 ------p
AnyObjectId[10fcef4b65f98c227c0639d207ee8f550c030b92]
```

Commit `10fcef4b65f98c227c0639d207ee8f550c030b92` does not appear anywhere in the repository, where did this identifier even come from? And most importantly, why does `tag.getObjectId()` not return  the identifier `1f74b8249ea41ebbe3305536def4b430130d366c`, which it should point to?

I've tried many things and the only way I could get to the correct commit reference from the tag was by invoking `RevTag::getObject()` (`RevTag` acquired via `RevWalk`).

Comment: I can't speak for JGit, but in regular old Git, an annotated tag is an object of its own, that contains data that include the hash ID of another object. So it looks like you're getting the hash ID of the annotated tag object referring to commit `10fcef4b65f98c227c0639d207ee8f550c030b92` that you just made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, JGit's `TagCommand` creates an annotated tag.
As [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) commented, the returned ref points to the tag object.

To create an unannotated tag, use `setAnnotated(false)`. The command will then return a ref that points to the tagged commit.

This post explains how to see the target commit ID of annotated tags and how to distinguish annotated from unannotated tags in JGit:
[List commits associated with a given tag with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149949/list-commits-associated-with-a-given-tag-with-jgit)